# Proof that $(-\lambda)v=-(\lambda v)$ and $\lambda(-v)=-(\lambda v)$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ and $v \in V.$

I'm trying to prove the following results (using the vector space axioms):

1) $(-\lambda)v=-(\lambda v)$

2) $\lambda(-v)=-(\lambda v)$

What I tried: 
1) $$\begin{align} (-\lambda)v&=\lambda(-1)v \\&=\lambda[0+(-1)v] \\&=\lambda[(-v+v)+(-1)v] \\&=\lambda [-v+(v+(-1)v)] \\&=\lambda [-v+(1v+(-1)v) \\&=\lambda[-v+(1+(-1))v] \\&=\lambda[-v+0v] \\&=\lambda[-v+0] \\&=\lambda(-v) \\&=-\lambda v\end{align}$$

Is this proof correct? Also, does anyone have a hint about starting 2)? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of (1) relies on the last equality $\lambda(-v)=-\lambda v$, but this is just (2), which follows because:
$$
\lambda(-v)+(\lambda v)=\lambda(-v+v)=\lambda\cdot 0=0,\\
(\lambda v)+\lambda(-v)=\lambda(v+(-v))=\lambda\cdot 0=0.
$$

Comment: What's the difference between your first line and your second line (since addition is commutative)? Also, is my proof for 1) correct?

Comment: The two lines show $a+b=b+a=0$ so $b=-a$ by definition. As for (1), please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically correct, but I prefer doing it in a different way. First I prove that $0v=\mathbf{0}$ for all vectors $v$, because

> $0v=(0+0)v=0v+0v$; adding $-(0v)$ to both sides gives $\mathbf{0}=0v$

Then I observe that

> $\lambda v+(-\lambda)v=(\lambda-\lambda)v=0v=\mathbf{0}$

so $(-\lambda)v$ is the opposite of $\lambda v$, which can be written
$$
(-\lambda)v=-(\lambda v)
$$
Similarly for the other equality which requires proving $\lambda \mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$ for all scalars $\lambda$.

Note: I use here $\mathbf{0}$ to denote the zero vector, for greater clarity.